# Why are form field __init__ methods being called on Django startup?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app with custom form fields, some of which have slow operations in their constructors. I was surprised recently to find out that those constructors were getting called when Django itself was starting up, even before a user does something that requires that form in a view.

Why are they getting instantiated at server start?

Example:

**urls.py:**

```
from myapp.views import view1
...
url(r'^test$', view1.test),
```

**views/view1.py:**

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
    field1 = MyChoiceField()

class MyChoiceField(ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, choices=(), required=True, widget=None, label=None,
             initial=None, help_text=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ChoiceField, self).__init__(required, widget, label, initial,
                                      help_text, *args, **kwargs)     
    self.choices = [(m.id, m.name) for m in ReallyLargeTableModel.objects.all()]
```

If I set a break point inside that field constructor, then start up Django, it breaks the first time I request any page, even if the view in question does not need that form or field. The stacktrace leads back to the import line in urls.py.

Is this because I'm importing view1 in urls.py, instead of importing view1.test?

**Edit:** This isn't Django specific, here is a test case the illustrates the behavior:

```
class Something():
    def __init__(self):
        print "Something __init__() called"

class UsesSomething():
    field = Something()
```

If you run this in the interactive terminal, it will print "Something **init**() called". This was surprising to me because I have not actually instantiated a UsesSomething object.

Comment: Never really paid attention honestly, because it's never mattered in my applications, but it doesn't feel right. `__init__` shouldn't be called until the class is instantiated. Usually, the class actually needs additional data that you must provide to run initialization anyways. Still, what happens if you forgo importing the view and simply use `url(r'^test$', 'myapp.views.view1.test'),` instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you instantiate the fields in the form definition, which is presumably being imported by one of your views.

The field init is the wrong place to do this sort of dynamic initialization, for this exact reason. You want something that is called when the form is initialized: ie, the form's `__init__`.

That said, you don't actually want to do this at all - you just need to use `forms.ModelChoiceField`, which takes a queryset and does the dynamic assignment of choices for you.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ReallyLargeTableModel.objects.all())
```

Comment: You are correct, but I'm still trying to understand why importing MyForm is calling the ModelChoiceField() constructor before I've actually instantiated a MyForm object. See my edit.

Comment: Because things declared at the class level - ie not inside `__init__` or another method - are class attributes. They are available to the class, not to any particular instance of it. A class definition is an executable piece of code, so calling a field within that definition will execute that call when the class is defined, ie on first import of its module.

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

```
class UsesSomething():
    field = Something()
```

The line of code `field = Something()` will execute when you import the containing module as Python processes the class definition. This is just how Python works. You can actually put arbitrary code inside a class definition.

module: test.py:

```
class UsesSomething():
    print "wow!"

>>> import test
wow!
```

Comment: I've been using Python for a couple of years, but this still surprised me. Probably because that would not happen in Java.

Comment: @ChaseSeibert Coming from C++, I was also surprised. But if you think about it, it makes sense. Normally you would just do attribute assignment or function definitions inside the class definition. Those attributes are class attributes that exist independently of any instances of that class. Remember that classes are first level objects in Python, so a class definition by itself is actually creating an object (not an instance of the class, but an actual class object).